# Is it possible to add a mock microphone and speaker to gitlab CI pipeline?

Tags: gitlab, pytest, gitlab-ci, pyaudio

I am using pytest to test some functions in a GitLab pipeline. However, some of these functions require a microphone or speakers to run, so the tests run correctly locally but not on the pipeline, yielding the following error which is called from pyaudio.PyAudio().

`FAILED tests/test_audio.py::test_audio_player - OSError: [Errno -9996] Invalid output device (no default output device)`

`FAILED tests/test_audio.py::test_audio_recorder - OSError: [Errno -9996] Invalid input device (no default output device)`

So I was wondering if there is any way I can add a default (mock / non-functioning) microphone and speakers to the GitLab pipeline so that these tests run.

Comment: Show your `test_audio.py` code and perhaps we can tell you what and how to mock

Answer (score 0):

You must install a driver on an agent which will act as a fake audio in/out. You can use [VB-Audio](https://vb-audio.com/Cable/index.htm) on Windows agent for example, not sure about Linux.

Comment: I tried adding the following to the before_script:
  - apt-get install -y pulseaudio |||
  - pulseaudio --start |||
  - pactl load-module module-virtual-sink sink_name=test_sink |||
  - pactl set-default-sink test_sink` |||
But it still doesn't detect a mic or speaker

Comment: So the sources and sinks are working in the environment, and are default, but pyaudio is not finding them